# Duplicate each number in a row n times, where n is the number in the row

Tags: awk, sed, foreach, vi

I have text files that each have a single column of numbers:

```
2
3
4
```

I want to duplicate each line `n` times, where `n` is the number in the row, so the output looks like this:

```
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

The only examples I have found used a fixed number of `n`.

I thought `sed` might be good to read each line, but I haven't been able to figure out how to tell `sed` to use the number in each line as the value for the of times the line should be duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Tis trivial in `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= $1; i++) print $0}'
```

Or, equivalently:

```
awk '{for (i = 0; i < $1; i++) print}'
```

Note that the code tests against `$1` rather than `$0`, but prints `$0` rather than `$1`.  This allows you to have an input such as:

```
12 Lords a-leaping
11 Ladies dancing
10 Drummers drumming
9 Pipers piping
8 Maids a-milking
7 Swans a-swimming
6 Geese a-laying
5 Gold rings
4 Calling birds
3 French hens
2 Turtle doves
1 Partridge in a pear tree
```

and you'll get rather copious output repeating the lines as often as the first number in the line dictates.